# Как устроено микроядро?

Tags: файловая-система, ядро

Думаю, вы знаете о нескольких типах ядра системы. Первый - монолитное ядро, типичные представители - современные Unix, а также Linux. Второй - микроядерная ОС, типичный представитель - MINIX, ещё парочка малоизвестных ОС. Конечно, MINIX opensource: однако я её не видел ни в виде img/ISO образа, ни в виде загружаемого для QEMU zImage. Попробую, конечно, собрать ОС из исходников, и посмотреть, что там, да как... Есть ещё GNU Hurd - это скорее ядро, как Linux. Есть даже сборки Debian с Hurd ядром. Читать исходники - это, конечно, хорошо, но хочется увидеть рабочее ядро хотя бы в QEMU.

Просто, смотрите. В чем особенность микроядра? Есть базовое ядро, которое обеспечивает самые базовые вещи - хоть какую-то работу с PCI, портами ввода-вывода, управления памятью. Все остальное - поддержка файловых систем, внешних устройств - осуществляется уже, по сути, отдельным процессом в userspace. Ну, условно это выглядит так:

```
/init
| /sbin/wifi-driver
| /sbin/keyboard-driver
```

[Поправьте, если я где-то ошибся, ибо в теме микроядер особо не разбираюсь].

Тут вопрос именно к, по сути, "драйверу файловой системы". Чтобы его запустить, нужно смонтировать раздел, где он лежит. Но чтобы смонтировать раздел - нужен драйвер/модуль ядра! Но ведь в микроядерных ОС файловая система работает в userspace -> т е есть условный `/sbin/fsmgr`. Но откуда он берётся, если файловой системы для ядра нету, если ничего не смонтировано?

Comment: Слишком много лишнего текста, уберите всё лишнее и оставьте только суть, вот к примеру всё что было до `Тут вопрос именно к, по сути...`, можно убрать.

Comment: хорошо, поправил

Comment: Если так идти, то получается, что микроядро должно быть совсем нулевого размера - все ведь можно вынести с него:) также приведенный текст в вопросе очень похож на проблему курица-яйцо. По факту, можно сделать двумя способами - либо драйвер файловой системы - часть ядра, либо загрузчик просто загружает в память все модули (а кто сказал, что они должны хранится именно в файловой системе? может они просто лежат на диске один за другим?), а ядро уже думает, что с ними делать

Comment: `Конечно, MINIX opensource: однако я её не видел ни в виде img/ISO образа` - ищется в три перехода [Official releases - x86 - CD images](https://wiki.minix3.org/doku.php?id=www:download:start), но похоже он уже всё, если судить по тому что уже 5 лет dev версия не обновлялась.

Comment: *`Но откуда он берётся, если файловой системы для ядра нету, если ничего не смонтировано?`*  Сразу скажу, как сделано в реальных системах, не знаю. Если вы об исполняемом коде fsmgr, то если бы я проектировал ОС с микроядром, то собрал этот код в том же загруочном файле, где и код микроядра. Он был бы загружен в DDR тем же загрузчиком, что запускает ядро. А init видел бы в специальной таблице, скомпонованной вместе с его кодом, в каких адресах лежит код для процесса fsmgr. Далее очевидно